# Add marker to google maps in ios using url scheme

Tags: ios, google-maps

When I tap on "Open in Google Maps" button in my application, I want my application to navigate to google maps application and open up the address that I specified and put a marker to it.

Here is my code for that purpose:

```
UIAlertAction* googleMaps = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"google_maps", @"Google Maps") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    NSString *customURL = @"comgooglemaps://?center=41.039400,28.994583&zoom=16&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0xff0000%7Clabel:1%7CVodafone+Arena+Stadyumu";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
}];
```

When I tap on the button, it correctly navigates to specific location. However, it does not put a marker to it. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Google doc, the format specified in your code is wrong:-

Example:-

```
comgooglemaps://?q=Vodafone+Arena+Stadyumu&center=41.039400,28.994583&zoom=15&views=transit
```

This shows the marker in the center of the map

Answer (score 1):

With new format of [Google Maps URL Scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme), we can't add a marker directly but there is a workaround for this you can pass your location(lat-long and name) as search query from URL and maps will show a marker as it shows while searching like this -

```
comgooglemaps://?q=Pizza&center=37.759748,-122.427135
```